# Redirect some .htm page to WordPress page without path and query string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to permanent redirect some .htm page from subdomain to main domain WordPress page, for this I am using this code

```
Redirect permanent /cat/FSBO76.htm http://www.example.com/cat/my-favorite/
```

But I am getting a problem normally my WordPress page working fine but when I click on old link its redirect with trailing query string and showing page not found error.

```
http://www.example.com/cat/my-favorite/?cat=FSBO76
```

Can anyone tell me how can I redirect without path and query string? or any way to solve this problem.

I already try with Redirect 301 also.

EDIT:  Its only happening for .htm files, all other files and directory redirecting properly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like maybe mod_alias (`Redirect`) and mod_rewrite is interferring with each other. If you already have wordpress rewrite rules in your htaccess file, you need to stick with mod_rewrite instead of using mod_alias here. Try using something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cat/FSBO76.htm$ http://www.example.com/cat/my-favorite/ [L,R=301]
```

where "subdomain.example.com" is your subdomain.

Comment: Thank you but after using your provided rule now old URL not redirecting.

Comment: Hello Sir, can you please help me about this?